# SAPUI5 NotificationBar in splitApp

Tags: notifications, resize, width, sapui5, master-detail

I have a NotificaitonBar-Control as content element of a detail view, which is a element of a splitApp.

In Google Chrome there is no problem, but on the iPad there is a display issue. The notificationBar is between the master- and the detail-View.

The masterview overcovers a part of the notificationBar and the detail-view did not.

How can I resize the notificationBar. I did not find any method or propertie to modify the notificationBar.

If I look at the API I do not understand why it does not match to the detailview:

> A NotificationBar is a "toolbar" that can be added to a page to show messages and notifications from the application. Its position, height and width is inherited from the element that the notification bar is added to.

[SAPUI5 NotificationBar API](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.ux3.NotificationBar.html)

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the namespace `sap.ui.ux3` I assume that the NotificationBar is not really responsive and therefore not working on smaller devices like the iPad.

I found a demopage for the NotificationBar which has some interesting information:

> If the NotificationBar should be smaller than per default a separate CSS-class must be added to the NotificationBar

This means you have to do the resizing via good old CSS. The example they gave looks similar to the following snippet.

**style.css** (or however your custom CSS file is named)

```
.slimNotificationBar {
     left : 60px;
     right: 100px;
}
```

To make it work on both iPad and Desktop, you should make it responsive by adding media querys (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

**Your.controller.js** (or however it's named)

```
// after instantiating your NotificationBar
oNotificationBar.addStyleClass("slimNotificationBar");
```

Link to the demopage: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/ux3/demokit/NotificationBar.html

---

However, if you prefer a built-in and responsive solution, you might want to try the following approach.

Add a `sap.m.Toolbar` to your detail page, which has a button that opens a `sap.m.MessagePopover`.

See the following example: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessagePopover/preview

Comment: Thanks this was the solution. Until now I used media queries to reach responsiveness, but maybe I will switch to your advice. Thanks!

Comment: [sap.ui.ux3 is not officially compatible with sap.m](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/36/3cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820/content.htm). So i would recommend to use a sap.m.Toolbar with MessagePopover too.